# Is there something like interceptor in Windows 8.1?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, windows-8.1, interceptor

I have this code repeated through my ViewModels (using MVVM Light):

```
        OperationInProgress = true;
        ServerConectionError = false;
        SomeData = null;

        try
        {

            SomeData = await _dataRepository.GetData();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            ServerConectionError = true;
        }
        finally
        {
            OperationInProgress = false;
        }
```

I have this code practically repeated in all my ViewModels (only changing the **GetData** method and **SomeData** property)

With AngularJS it would be easy to reuse this code, but....what about Windows 8.1? Some idea?

Comment: Your problem is not clear for me. Try to use separate method for this piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [postsharp](https://www.postsharp.net/).

In PostSharp you can attach aspect attributes to your assemblies, namespaces, classes, and methods.
Thus, these aspects can be used for crosscutting concerns such as logging, exceptions, security, etc.